# Bibliography Icon and natbib package are conflicting for APAlike style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

I want bibliography icons and `Author (Year)` on my beamer. If I include `\usepackage(natbib)` I will get the `Author (Year)` APAlike bibliography style that I want but I will not get the `bibliography icons` on my reference. Inversely, if I disable the `\usepackage(natbib)` I will **NOT get the `Author (Year)` APAlike bibliography style** that I want but I will get the `bibliography icons` on my reference as you can see it in my MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% begin bib
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade49,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1949",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
\end{filecontents}
%end bib
%\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

I do not want this style \cite{goossens86}\\ nor \cite{greenwade49}

\end{frame}
%%bib config 

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{~}
    \frametitle[]{~}
    \def\newblock{}
    %\begin{block}[allowblockbreaks]{~}
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**I want to retain the `bibliography icons` the `Author (Year)` APAlike style**

Comment: i am available for any further clarification you may want to ask.

Comment: You might want to show some images of what it is suppose to look like. With our examples I see icons in the bibliography frame

Comment: you mean when `\usepackage(natbib)`  is included in the code?